# ScalaCheck collection generator

Tags: scalacheck

I'm using Scalacheck and want to generate collection of a given size. There is a special function for that in scalaCheck, `Gen.listOfN(size, Gen[T])`.
When in `forAll` method I print the size of the generated collection it does not always have the defined size. Actually it only has the given size on the first attempt. For example, size 6 --> first attempt the size of collection is 6, second attempt size is only 3. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might be using an old (pre-1.11.0) version of ScalaCheck. In these versions, the generator boundaries weren't always respected.

When ScalaCheck finds a failing test case for your property, it tries to simplify that test case (make it "smaller"). Nowadays (version >= 1.11.0), ScalaCheck tries to respect for example `listOfN` when doing this simplification, and not test lists with fewer than `n` items. However, in some cases it is still not possible for ScalaCheck to know what boundaries a generator had from the start, for example when you use the `Gen.map` method.

For more information on the cases when ScalaCheck still might simplify test cases in unexpected ways (and what you can do to mitigate it), see: [Scalacheck won't properly report the failing case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037900/scalacheck-wont-properly-report-the-failing-case/20060505#20060505)

Comment: Are you aware of any guidelines on how to avoid using `map` to avoid boundary (or other meta) information getting lost?

Comment: The only general advice is to simply add back your generator's invariant by using the `Gen.suchThat` method. The generator/shrinking functionality is target for improvement, so if you have any specific use cases that you find troublesome, I'd be happy to hear about them.